# What values to put into npm init when following workaround instructions to get eslint working in sfdx project?

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code, eslint

I'm experiencing the same problem as the poser of this question:

[Why is ESLint not working properly for Lightning Web Components in VS Code and how to make it work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296012/why-is-eslint-not-working-properly-for-lightning-web-components-in-vs-code-and-h)

One of the steps is to run npm init which asks a bunch of questions. What values should be provided in response?

I was unable to ask this as a comment on the original answer due to low rep.

Comment: From the wealth of info sfdxfox provided, the following steps got me where I wanted to be

npm install followed by ctrl-shift-p : ESLint:Manage Library Execution : Allow Everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `npm init` if you use `force:project:create`. I just did a test to verify, and the diff between what `force:project:create` and all `npm init` does is:

```
@@ -39,5 +39,8 @@
     "**/{aura|lwc}/**": [
       "eslint"
     ]
-  }
+  },
+  "main": "index.js",
+  "author": "",
+  "license": "ISC"
 }
```

In other words, it adds a little extra info that you don't need (because you're not making an npm package, you're using it to save your dependencies and scripts).

If you insist on doing `npm init` anyways, just press Enter/Return to accept all defaults (unless you want to provide any extra details). There's no need to do anything here.

It's worth noting that apparently, babel-eslint is already present when you `force:project:create` (maybe it was accidentally removed in a previous release?)

What you *do* want to do is run `npm install`, as this actually installs a number of dependencies, and almost everything else you need to get things up and running.

The default `force:package:create` and subsequent installation of the Salesforce Extension Pack won't fully fix a myriad of small problems you'll encounter until you run `npm install`.

Finally, the install steps seem to be incorrect; some of the referenced packages are deprecated. Instead, run:

```
npm install eslint@6.x typescript @lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc @salesforce/eslint-config-lwc --save-dev
```

**NOTE TO FUTURE VISITORS**

At some point, you may get warnings about things being deprecated or other unmet peer dependencies. If you see this, you need to select a new version of plugins until you run out of deprecated messages (if possible), and unmet peer dependencies.

For example:

```
npm WARN eslint-plugin-compat@3.3.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

This means you've installed the wrong version of `eslint`.

You may need to adjust the above installation command to fix this problem.

You may get some "npm WARN deprecated" messages, too. In that case, nothing you can do until the package maintainers for LWC plugins updates their manifest to use new projects (which also typically means altering code, so be patient).